# How to decompose a Java Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a java program   dealing with signal arrays.

This array is got by converting midi file into midi-text file:

```
Signal [] sig= {"a1a2a3", "b1b2b3", "c1c2c3", "d1d2d3"};



Signal [] sig1 = {"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"};
Signal [] sig2 = {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"};
Signal [] sig3 = {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3"};
```

How it can be achieved?

Comment: `a1a2a3` is of type `Signal` or `String` ? if it's a `String` you can split/substring it, otherwise it's a pointer to an object...

Comment: What's in Signal Class ?

Comment: why you store strings on array and again you want to break them? We can make three arrays while you construct first single array.Make question more clear.

Comment: how/where do you get `Signal[] sig`? Instead of `a1a2a3`, can you have it something like `a1-a2-a3`?

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, such arrays are got by converting midi files into text-midi. So over midi files I have no control, but I will have to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about **MultiMap**?

> **I think you can implement multimap while creating original array.**

Go through : http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Simple solution would be like that:

If a array is like

```
Signal [] sig= {a1a2a3, b1b2b3, c1c2c3, d1d2d3};
for(int i = 0;i<sig.size();i++){
for(int j = 0;j<sig[i].length() ;j++){
newArray.add(sig.subString(j,j+1));
}
}
```

You can do by string manipulation like that. Is it ok?

Comment: Hi Sanjaya Pandey, thanks for the   easiest way to tackle the toughest.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Signal[]> list = new ArrayList<Signa[]>();
for(Signal s : sig)
  list.add(s.split());

int X = list.get(0).size();
int Y = sig.length()
Signal[][] sigs = new Signal[X][Y];
for(int i=0; i<X; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<Y; j++)
    sigs[i][j] = list(i)[j];

Signal[] sig1 = sigs[0];
...
```

you need to add a split method to `Signal` class:

```
class Signal {
  ....

  public Signal[] split() {
    // split signals
  }
}
```